# Kentico AD Auth and 403 error

Tags: kentico

I'm drawing a blank here. I'm attempting to set up AD authentication to the CMS Desk, the site will be public. I follow the documentation (https://docs.kentico.com/k9/managing-users/user-registration-and-authentication/configuring-windows-ad-authentication), but after enabling Windows Auth in IIS, i get a 403 error.

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I checked the user table and my AD account was there. Not getting the login as i'm logged into my laptop was the part i was missing.